# javaScript HTML Parsing

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get parse HTML document.

this is the HTML:

```
<div>
    <a class="profilePicThumb" href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=669986173135523&amp;set=a.219741158160029.56045.100003724408511&amp;type=3&amp;source=11" rel="theater">
        <img class="profilePic img" alt="Zinedine Zidane" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xtp1/v/t1.0-1/p160x160/11817031_669986173135523_8947137909221952926_n.jpg?oh=e21bb7d0d03858df94987c62e64a6022&amp;oe=56904830&amp;__gda__=1455998716_5401014ec3ef47b8bffd62207c57fda0" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I need to get the picture and the name.

I try this code:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("profilePic img");
```

Anyone can help me?
I'm new in javaScript...

Thanks

Comment: Use `document.querySelector('.profilePic.img').alt`

Comment: or just `document.querySelector('.profilePic").alt`

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return an array of matched elements.  This is what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: @Tushar its working... Thanks...

Comment: @user3460154 Welcome! Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine and correctly finds the HTMLImageElment, see below:

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("profilePic img");
document.write("<b>Number of element:</b>" + list.length + '<br>');
document.write("<b>alt: </b>" + list[0].alt + '<br>')
document.write("<b>src: </b>" + list[0].src + '<br>')
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="profilePicThumb" href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=669986173135523&amp;set=a.219741158160029.56045.100003724408511&amp;type=3&amp;source=11" rel="theater">
    <img class="profilePic img" alt="Zinedine Zidane" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xtp1/v/t1.0-1/p160x160/11817031_669986173135523_8947137909221952926_n.jpg?oh=e21bb7d0d03858df94987c62e64a6022&amp;oe=56904830&amp;__gda__=1455998716_5401014ec3ef47b8bffd62207c57fda0"
    />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `list` assignment is ok. Just use:

```
if list.length > 0 {
    var name = list[0].alt;
    var url = list[0].src;

    // whatever you want to do with name and url
}
```